# Highlighting text in a textbox without using RichTextBox control

Tags: wpf, textbox, richtextbox, highlighting

I have a WPF textbox (not a RichTextBox) and inside this textbox, I want to highlight search results (like in web browsers)

For example if I search for "abc", all occurences of "abc" should be highlighted (for example, with some red background or font)

I want to know if this is possible without using RichTextBox control, or not really?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible but it's much more easy to use a `RichTextBox` so you may consider to use that instead, moreover you cannot change font size but only color (background and/or foreground) and effects.

First you have to derive your own class from `TextBox` because you'll override its render method. Now override the `OnRender()` method, here you'll use the `DrawingContext.DrawText()` method to draw the text (place everything inside a `FormattedText` object, primary you'll have to adjust its properties to make it similar to a standard `TextBox`).

Now what you have is a plain `TextBox` where **in addition** you draw your text. From this starting point you can choose to:

- Completely override `TextBox` text drawing: set `TextBox.Foreground` property to `Brushes.Transparent`. User will interact with "real" text but he'll see the text your draw. Please note that to make this works you have to mimic exactly how text is drawn (if you change font size, for example, then they'll be unaligned) in the original `TextBox`.
- Add the highlight feature you need keeping the base `TextBox` text drawing: calculate where the text you want to highlight is and then draw the proper background.

**References**
This (simplified!) algorithm comes from [CodeBox2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35413/CodeBox-2-An-Extended-and-Improved-Version-of-the), it was originally designed to extend a `TextBox` with some simple editor-like features.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried the first method (completely override the text drawing) - it works fine until TextWrapping comes into play... 
I don't have any idea how to calculate the highlighted text position (the other method).

Comment: @Zsolt yes it can be a little bit tricky but you can use FormattedText (again must match exactly TextBox settings) where text to highlight is in the right color/background and everything else is transparent.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in functionality for this. Also, the TextBox only supports a single fontstyle for the entire text.

If the text should be read-only, you could use a flow or fixed document and format the text in Run Elements.